# Animation Transformation doesn't persist on View when clearAnimation() called on View

Tags: java, android, animation, kotlin

I am applying an infinite repeat count rotate animation on a circular view for my music player app.

When I start the animation on the view [that is, press play button on the music], the view flawlessly rotates infinitely.

You can see the preview images of the view here:

https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-yYnCxksY8IQ/WxAaHcxcA7I/AAAAAAAAAtI/i86w09gbXhIC4LpKknWFbvXgrBwTjr8ugCLcBGAs/s1600/Screenshot_2018-05-31-20-44-26-684.jpeg

https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-C-SR7dsZwKc/WxAaJxRcWXI/AAAAAAAAAtU/K5_U52DVWcwaYkeTdvptoM-lUApliNKKgCLcBGAs/s1600/Screenshot_2018-05-31-20-44-45-739.jpeg

The problem is that when I call the clearAnimation() [to stop animation when pause music button is clicked], the view abrubtly transforms to its initial state, that doesn't look good.

I want the view to stay at the exact rotation as when it is rotated till the pause button was clicked. For example, when I click play, the animation rotates the view to 30 degrees and then I press pause, the view should stop at that 30 degrees position.

Files:

Rotation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true">
<rotate
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
</set>
```

Clearing Animation:

```
private fun stopDiskAnimation() {
    v.rotate_view_album_art.clearAnimation()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Animator` should help you

```
val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourView, "rotation", 0f, 360f).apply {
    duration = 5000
    repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
    start()
}
// ...
animator.pause()
```

Resource:

http://cogitolearning.co.uk/2014/01/android-property-animations-controlling-animation-flow/

Comment: Thank you for your response Taras. I was actually firing an Eventbus pause event on the pause function that didn't call the above function. That was the issue. Still, I value your efforts, so thanks.